# Unable to create native threads after creating 2700 threads

Tags: java, multithreading

In my application I need to make use of multiple threads to make it work faster but I have been facing a situation where it says that unable to create native threads. 
I have read that it is the RAM which decides the number of the threads a program can have which depends on the number of threads*stack size for each thread.

How do we know the stack size for a thread in Java? Can I decide stack size for thread on my own?

Comment: Not enough information here for us to try and reproduce, or even understand your problem fully. Try sharing some code and/or the exception message you've encountered.

Comment: With all due respect, if you need to create 2700 threads, most probably it is you who has a problem...

Comment: At 2700 threads, the overhead of context switches will probably make your program go *slower*. Try instead to use system introspection to get the number of CPU cores and launch one thread per core.

Answer (score 2):

The number of native threads you can create depends on the OS. It's rather the OS that stops you from going to such a huge number, not the memory size.

Comment: that is what I want to know. what is the limit of an operating system?

Comment: That number might depend not only on the OS, but also the underlying hardware. Does is therefore really make sense to know this number at compile time?

Comment: I doubt there is a way to figure out the exact number.